# slf4j log not print anything in bean initialize method with @RequestScope

Tags: java, spring, slf4j

My bean definition code is looks like this.

```
    @Configuration
    public class BeanConfig {
        private org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanConfig.class);

        @Bean
        @RequestScope //remove this and the slf4j log print well again!
        public SomeBean someBean() {
            SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean();
            log.error("init bean ~~~ {}", someBean); 
            System.out.println("init bean ~~~ {}" + someBean); 
            return someBean;
        }
    }
```

The problem is : the slf4j log didn't print anything, only `System.out.println` part can print.

I can confirm my slf4j log setting is correct(it's spring boot 2.0.8 default setting), and other slf4j log work well.

And I don't see any error message.

Comment: are you sure that the sysout is getting printed for each request and only log is not working?

Comment: @Hareesh yes...

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestScope` 
the bean `SomeBean` will be init everytimes when it is be used.
it will not be init when the project run. 
u can check it carefully!

if remove `@RequestScope` ,then bean will be init when the project start! so u can see the log

Comment: ya, I know, but I still only see log from `System.out.println`

Comment: Even I am facing the exact same issue. Slf4j for some reason does not print any logs inside methods annotated with `@RequestScope` and my use case requires that method be annotated with `@RequestScope`. Can someone provide a solution for this?